# Migration of Drupal website from live server to local server shows broken links

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

I am new to drupal.I have to work on Live website with drupal 7. This website is working fine. I downloaded the website on my localhost.Home page of the website works fine.But when I click on any link in menu it shows me page not found.When I checked the url it is showing me like this:

```
http://Locahost/page/category/she.php
```

But when I check my project page and category folders arenot present.Also when I searched on live website these folder are not there also. But on live server it works fine.Url on live server is like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/page/category/she.php
```

But Page and category folders are not there. I am a new to drupal. Any help to resolve this url generation issue will be appreciated.

Comment: page and category are friendly url's set inside drupal, not actual file system directories. everything goes to index.php and drupal determines which node to display. something is not set the same as your live site.

Comment: How to remove this friendly URL on my localhost for testing. Also on my local server i am not able to access admin area. @Avibodha

Comment: did you copy over the server's .htaccess (if apache) to your local setup?

Comment: Try access login page like so `http://Locahost/?q=user` and tell us the results

Comment: Did you copy the same database over on the live site? Where are you hosting it? Did you make sure an .htaccess file is present in the live site?

Comment: Probable issues: 1) You missed the .htaccess file when downloading the site (its a hidden file so if you drag-droped you probably missed it); 2) You're local apache configuration doesn't have the `AllowOverride All` directive set for in the applicable `<Directory>` block; 3) Pretty URLs are disabled in your local installation; try going to: http://your-localhost/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls

Answer (score 0):

After checking for possible misconfogurations as outlined by jpschroeder's you could try using the Backup and Migrate module.

Use the default settings and the cache tables will not be saved in your backup. You don't need them, as they will be re-created on the new server as pages are served for the first time there.

There's a good tutorial on this at  http://www.seascapewebdesign.com/blog/how-transfer-your-website-one-server-another